# Android create shadow effect on layout or views

Tags: android, view, viewflow

can anyone suggest how can i give shadow to particular view or layout..here is image what i want actually:

[image]

you can see dark shadow at cover flow (behind dots). does any one has idea about ?

Answer will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://www.uifuel.com/android-creating-a-drop-shadow-in-xml-layout/ try this link it will be useful for you <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> <gradient android:startColor="startcolrhere" android:centerColor="endcolor here" android:endColor="#2e3436" android:angle="90" />
</shape> use it in Relavtive Layout alignbottom to the image

Answer (score 0):

Create an image for it(overlay). Give it alpha as it goes upwards. Place it below the dots.